# Duplex communication via bluetooth - in C++ code

Tags: bluetooth, c++

I have a working C++ code , partially converted to class, passing single (text char ) message form client (Rpi) to server (PC). 
I have used a composite ( fancy work for hack )  of many C/C++ code available on internet.

My next step is to reverse the communication path - from server back to client - to accomplish two way communication. 
( Two way simplex, true duplex is not necessary ).

The purpose is to notify client to send another message.
If anybody is interested participating / helping I would appreciate  that.

Please note - I am working in C++ code and at this point passing JUST test text (char) messages.

Comment: do you have a question that you would like to ask?

Comment: `If anybody is interested participating` : sorry but without any C++ source code and your progress it is complicated. `I have a working C++ code message form client (Rpi) to server (PC)`. I assume you receive and read your message. If you do that you have all for doing what you want to do. You should have `Tx` (RPi) and `Rx` function (PC). Put the Rx function after the Tx function on the RPi and put the Tx function  after the Rx function on your PC ?

Comment: NO after these comments I do not see any point asking questions.

Comment: @JanHus, Are you the user who asked the original question?

Answer (score 2):

Example server side :

```
    // accept one connection
    client = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &opt);

    // read data from the client (Rx)
    bytes_read = read(client, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if( bytes_read > 0 ) {
        printf("received [%s]\n", buf);
        if(strncmp(buf[0], 'A', 1) == 0){    
            /* send a response to the client (Tx)
            At this time the client must be listening with the read() function 
            that you will have placed after the Tx function
            */
            write(client, "I receive 'A' char", 18);
        }else if(strncmp(buf[0], 'B', 1) == 0){ 
            /* send a response to the client (Tx)
            At this time the client must be listening with the read() function 
            that you will have placed after the Tx function
            */
            write(client, "I receive 'B' char", 18);
        }else{
            //...
        }
    }
```

Comment: So in an essence I can both read and write to file descriptor generated by accept. Switching from  RX to TX and vice versa is obviously given.

Comment: @JanHus, Are you the user who asked the original question?